# General representation of a linear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning linear algebra for the first time from the book *Linear Algebra* by Shilov. On page 76, it introduces the "general representation of a linear form" as follows:

[image: general representation of a linear form]

I can't understand how $l_k$ turns into $\varepsilon_k$ and then back into $l_k$.

Comment: It looks like it should be
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k e_k$$
instead of
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{n} l_k e_k.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error. It should be $x=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k e_k.$ Then,
$$
L(x) = L(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k e_k)
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k L(e_k)
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_k l_k,
$$
where linearity of $L$ has been used to extract summation and coefficients out of $L.$